# Unknown option '\eu@zf@math' for package fontspec

Tags: mathspec

First a minimal working sample is as follows.

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{mathspec}



\begin{document}

Some words.

\end{document}
```

Compiling the `tex` file as above by `XeLaTeX` on MacTeX 2024 (the latest version), it will produce the error as follows.

```
Unknown option '\eu@zf@math' for package fontspec. ...Package[\eu@zf@math]{fontspec}[2008/08/09]
```

**Then how to eliminate the error?**

Comment: I get errors with each tested version of TeX Live, that is, from 2015 to 2024.

Comment: Annoying error, I'd say, but innocuous. Anyway, I'd also recommend to avoid `mathspec`, because it does damages to `fontspec`

Comment: @egreg I get errors only from 2024. I found that `fontspec` was updated on 13th Feb., 2024. So the error may be related to it.

Comment: No, also with TL 2023 I get an error (albeit different). Where's the problem? It lies in the combination with `ctexbook` and `mathspec`. By the way, `mathspec` does “patch” `fontspec` and it's quite likely that updates to the latter can break the former.

Comment: @egreg Is there anyway to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mathspec` package has problems with `ctexbook`. But it also has problems with `fontspec` because it patches it in possibly dangerous ways.

You can do the following at your own risk.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\documentclass{ctexbook}

%%%% Fix the error
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewCommandCopy{\kernelRequirePackage}{\RequirePackage}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\RequirePackage}{O{}mo}
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnF { #2 } { fontspec }
   {
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{\kernelRequirePackage[#1]{#2}}{\kernelRequirePackage[#1]{#2}[#3]}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{mathspec}
\RenewCommandCopy{\RequirePackage}{\kernelRequirePackage}
%%%

\begin{document}

Some words.

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `ctexbook` already loads `fontspec` so I disable `mathspec` trying to load it (where the error happens) and pass it the `no-math` option at the beginning.

I see no real reason to use `mathspec` nowadays.

Comment: I use `\mathspec` to invoke `otf` fonts on pc.

Comment: @M.Logic Use `unicode-math` instead.